# What would cause an Android ImageView to partially decode?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am trying to track down a bug that I can only explain as it's as if the image within my ImageView isn't fully decoding - I get a peek of the top of my image, but the rest of the image draws as pure white. I attached a debugger but do not see any error messages output, such as memory constraints. Here is a partial screenshot from my Activity:

[image: problem]

I am overlaying a series of ImageViews on top of one another, like a stack of cards. Here is an annotation of the screenshot, so you can see why this is wrong:

[image: annotation]

If I rotate my device, which has the effect of re-running onCreate, the ImageView draws correctly. I am using [Square's picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library to manage download and decode. I checked the filesystem for the file itself that represents the image, and the file is fine and fully downloaded.

I seem to be able to repro this behavior 1 out of every 10 times or so, which is enough to be problematic for my users.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening? The device on which I reproed was a Nexus 5 running Android L, but I have also seen this on a colleague's device running Android KitKat on a Samsung Galaxy 4.

For the record, I am running picasso 2.4.0 (a fork of Picasso from January 20th, 2015).

Comment: few bugs list here -->https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/530 , if the content length is huge , it may misbehave

Comment: I looked at that list but didn't see anything that matched my experience. The thread began mid-year last year; hopefully my fork would have incorporated fixes. Further, is it normal for a decoder to only decode the top of any image? Isn't it typically an all-or-nothing proposition?

Comment: Whats controlling the 'stack' of image views? Does it have 'recycling' on the bottom 95% of any imgvw card that is not the top-of-stack? Can it loseit placeholder on the view at top and inadvertently recycle making its view look like others which have been overlay by younger cards on stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, this was the [germane comment from this thread](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/836):

> I fixed with the below code in NetworkRequestHandler.java... When the network was broken, I think it will decode a half photo

I was able to 100% repro this issue when, on my test server, I returned a subset of the JPEG image instead of the entire JPEG image. It would seem that broken HTTP connections (or bad file servers) that only return a subset of data trigger this issue. I use a custom networking library that I plug into Picasso (instead of [okhttp](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader.html)), and I simply modified that library to ensure that the file length matched the server reported content-length before storing and decoding the file.

Answer (score 0):

This post on Picasso describes what I have been experiencing:

[I get half photo and half white color, and sometimes I get only the white color. #836](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/836)

One commenter on the thread says:

> remove the android:scaleType attribute and check to see if error still exists...I usually dont get that error when remove the scaleType attribute from a custom ImageView and use the fit() method in picasso which is reliable.

It turns out I was, in fact, including a "scaleType" attribute of "centerCrop" on the imageView into which I was loading. I have removed this attribute in favor of `.fit().centerCrop()`,  and haven't seen this issue since; will update this thread if I do.